# NullPointerException while reading txt file

Tags: java, debugging, nullpointerexception

Below is part of a program I've written to iterate through a file to find and compare two seperate numbers.

It searches each line for the start point where the line is equal to **"[Device|Sensors|Checksum]"**.  It then looks for the first and second occurrences of **"Value"**, gets the Hex number on that line, converts it to  type *long*. If these two long numbers are equal we're good, otherwise we report a problem

Here's an extract of the file I'm using

```
Address(18) = 0x0053
Page(18) = Sensor
Value(19) = 0x1
Desc(19) = used bytes from high priority task
Address(19) = 0x0053
Byte_No(19) = 2
Page(19) = Sensor
;end of section [Device|Sensors|Stack]
[Device|Sensors|Checksum]
Address(18) = 0x0053
Page(18) = Sensor
Value(2) = 0xE0A64F36
Address(18) = 0x0053
Page(18) = Sensor
Default(19) = 0x00
Value(3) = 0xE0A64F36
Page(18) = Sensor
Desc(19) = used bytes from high priority task
;end of section [Device|Sensors|Checksum]
```

I cannot find what exactly is wrong with this code despite trying to debug it already. The loops I've used seem sound.

```
try {

 do {//read line then check if line is "[Device|Sensors|Checksum]" WHILE line isn't ";end of section [Device|Sensors|Checksum]"                    

  line = reader.readLine();//Reads all lines up to "[Device|Sensors|Checksum]"

  if (line.equals("[Device|Sensors|Checksum]")) { //IF line is "[Device|Sensors|Checksum]" then  
                                                  //(check if line is "Value") ELSE read next line                    
   do {// DO read line and (check if line is "Value") WHILE line doesn't contain "Value"

     line = reader.readLine();//Reads all line up to first "Value"

     if (line.contains("Value")) { // IF line is "Value" then retrieve necessary value
                                   // ELSE read next line

      Hex1 = line.split("=")[1].trim();
      l1 = Long.parseLong(Hex1.substring(2), 16);
      JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("JOptionPane showMessageDialog example");
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame1, "Value has hex number\n " + Hex1 + "\n\n and integer\n" + l1 + "\n");

      System.out.println("Here's the line read  " + line);
      System.out.println("Here's the hex number from the line  " + Hex1);
      System.out.println("Here's the integer from the hex number  " + l1 + "\n");

      break;
     }
    } while (!"Value".contains(line = reader.readLine()));//while2 


   line = reader.readLine();  //Reads the line AFTER the first "Value" has been found

    do {//  Read line and check if line has "Value" WHILE line doesn't contain "Value"

     line = reader.readLine();//Reads all lines up to second "Value"

     if (line.contains("Value")) { // IF line is "Value" then retrieve necessary value
                                   // ELSE read next line

      Hex2 = line.split("=")[1].trim();
      l2 = Long.parseLong(Hex2.substring(2), 16);
      JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("JOptionPane showMessageDialog example");
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame2, "Value has hex number\n " + Hex2 + "\n\n and integer\n" + l2 + "\n");

      System.out.println("Here's the line read  " + line);
      System.out.println("Here's the hex number from the line  " + Hex2);
      System.out.println("Here's the integer from the hex number  " + l2 + "\n");

      break;

     }
    } while (!"Value".contains(line = reader.readLine()));
   }
  } while (!";end of section [Device|Sensors|Checksum]".equals(line = reader.readLine())); 
 if (l1 == l2) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Both checksum values ARE equal!");
   int status1 = 0;
   System.exit(status1);
 } else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Both checksum values NOT equal");
    int status2 = 0;
    System.exit(status2);
  }

} catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println("IO Exception. Could not read file!");
}
```

EDIT

The output and Stack Trace for the NPE is

```
run:
Here's the line read  Value(2) = 0xE0A64F36
Here's the hex number from the line  0xE0A64F36
Here's the integer from the hex number  3768995638

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at robertskostalproject.checksumFinder.HexFinder(checksumFinder.java:32)
at robertskostalproject.checksumGUI.askDirectory(checksumGUI.java:43)
at robertskostalproject.RobertsKostalProject.main(RobertsKostalProject.java:18)
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 11 seconds)
```

Comment: Did you really *mean* to skip the line directly after `[Device|Sensosrs|Checksum]`? Also, it doesn't help that your code is badly indented, you haven't told us where you got the exception, or what the file looks like, or what happens when you're not debugging. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: Please don't swear on SO (not even the quite mild swearing usedin your title).

Comment: And `"Value".contains(variable)`?

Comment: Check `line` for null before this `if (line.contains("Value(2)"))`

Comment: ALWAYS post the complete and exact stack trace of the exception.

Comment: For future reference, if you post regarding a `NullPointerException` PLEASE tell us at what LINE the NPE was thrown not just "in this block of code"

Comment: Appologies for the mild swearing. The question "What's wrong with this code" was already taken and this was already getting on my nerves. @Jon Skeet I've been changing around this code over and over. The _readLine_ command doesn't make any difference I just forgot to take it out.

Comment: Every time I try to format the code in this question nothing happens! I'm really trying but nothing seems to work. I've read through the formatting help and done the necessary spaces but still nothing. I'm at work and only have access to Internat Explorer. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: @RobertEnglish: Perhaps you're using tabs? Stack Overflow doesn't really work well with tabs - try spaces instead.

Comment: No, tabs never worked in the first place. I was using spaces all along

Comment: My indenting problem was due to Windows Internet Explorer being in Compatability mode. All's fixed now (Maybe less downvotes please?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I have now. Not a lot of change and it works, thankfully!

```
class checksumFinder {

public static long l1 = 1;
public static long l2 = 0;
//Default to not equal

String HexFinder(JFileChooser inFileName, String line, String Hex1, String Hex2)
throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    File file = inFileName.getSelectedFile();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    try {

      line = reader.readLine();//Read all lines up to "[Device|Sensors|Checksum]"

      do {//Read line then check if line is "[Device|Sensors|Checksum]" WHILE isn't ";end of section [Device|Sensors|Checksum]"                    

        line = reader.readLine();

        if (line.equals("[Device|Sensors|Checksum]")) { //IF line is "[Device|Sensors|Checksum]" then  
                                                        //(check if line is "Value") ELSE read next line                    
          do {// DO read line and check line is "Value" WHILE line doesn't contain "Value"

            if (line.contains("Value")) { //IF line is "Value" then retrieve necessary value
                                          // ELSE read next line

              Hex1 = line.split("=")[1].trim();
              l1 = Long.parseLong(Hex1.substring(2), 16);
              JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("JOptionPane showMessageDialog example");
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame1, "Value has hex number\n " + Hex1 + "\n\n and integer\n" + l1 + "\n");

              System.out.println("Here's the line read  " + line);
              System.out.println("Here's the hex number from the line  " + Hex1);
              System.out.println("Here's the integer from the hex number  " + l1 + "\n");

              break;
            }
          } while (!"Value".contains(line = reader.readLine()));//while2   

          line = reader.readLine();  //Read the line AFTER first "Value" has been found

          do {//Read line and check if line has "Value" WHILE line doesn't contain "Value"

           if (line.contains("Value")) { // IF line is "Value" then retrieve necessary value
                                        // ELSE read next line

             Hex2 = line.split("=")[1].trim();
             l2 = Long.parseLong(Hex2.substring(2), 16);
             JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("JOptionPane showMessageDialog example");
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame2, "Value has hex number\n " + Hex2 + "\n\n and integer\n" + l2 + "\n");

             System.out.println("Here's the line read  " + line);
             System.out.println("Here's the hex number from the line  " + Hex2);
             System.out.println("Here's the integer from the hex number  " + l2 + "\n");

             break;
           }
         } while (!"Value".contains(line = reader.readLine()));//while3

         while (!";end of section [Device|Sensors|Checksum]".equals(line)){
            line = reader.readLine();
         }
       }
     } while (!";end of section [Device|Sensors|Checksum]".equals(line)); //while1

     if (l1 == l2) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Both checksum values ARE equal!");
       int status1 = 0;
       System.exit(status1);
     } else {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Both checksum values NOT equal");
       int status2 = 0;
       System.exit(status2);
     }

 } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("IO Exception. Could not read file!");
 }
   return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Since you haven't specified *where* "in the 2nd while loop" you get the NPE, I'll just quote [BufferedReader#readLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29):

> Returns: A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, **or null** if the end of the stream has been reached

Additionally, you're using a `frame2` variable we haven't seen initialized.

Comment: +1 - `null` from `readLine()` is the most likely cause of the OP's NPE problem.  And even if the actual cause is something else, this is a *potential* cause ... depending on what is in the input stream.